# Visualizar informacion desde un json con angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, constructor

Tengo un json creado con informacion que quiero vizualizar en la pagina con el uso de {{}} y para hacer esto uso el modulo Http y de un servicio, pero para esto tengo que agregar en el constructor del header y el footer (que es donde quiero vizualizar la informacion) pero me manda error el servidor de ng y ya no se que hacer.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que estaría mejor si colocaras tu código en vez de fotos del mismo, para así la persona que te pueda ayudar pueda copiar y pergarlo con el fix en la respuesta.

Comment: puedes subir el código de tu informacion.servicio?

Answer (score 0):

por lo que puedo ver tienes mal escrita la palabra constructor ademas de esto deberias poner la variable con el accesor private, o sea deberia ser asi:

```
constructor(private _is: InformacionService){}
```